# ISInDesignMode Property is not working properly

Tags: mvvm-light

I'm having an issue where the property IsInDesignMode is not returning the expected value of true when running the solution in VS or Blend. My environment consists of Win Server 2008 R2, VS2010 Pro, Blend 4 and MVVM Light V3. I run my Silverlight 4 solution in Debug mode from VS and Blend, and IsInDesignMode is always false. Am I missing a setting? Is there a reason why it may not be picking up the environment? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVVM Light IsInDesignMode property not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303024/mvvm-light-isindesignmode-property-not-working)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should work properly. The only place where I know that IsInDesignMode returns a wrong value is when using it to build code that runs within Visual Studio, such as VS plug-ins. This is an issue that is very difficult to solve. It doesn't sound like it is what you are doing, though...

Do you have a repro that I can test? Alternatively, could you download the MVVM Light code and debug this?

Comment: This thread should be deleted; it's an exact duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303024/mvvm-light-isindesignmode-property-not-working)

Comment: Hey, you are missing "Thanks, Laurent" paragraph in your answer. Without it it feels incomplete.